# how to bump elasticsearch 'processors' setting in order to increase thread_pool.bulk.size?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

We've done pretty extensive performance analysis and found that our write heavy-Elasticsearch 
5.5.1-based application is under-utilizing CPU resources (load average is about same as number of cores, 
and we are 25% idle across all nodes). Since we are not bottlenecked on I/O or network, 
we decided to increase the number of threads that the /hot_threads API flagged as the 
busiest: namely, the ones in the bulk indexing thread pool.

However, the only way to do increase the size of this pool  is to increase the 
number of processors, which seems to be a rather tricky task, 
with not much associated documentation (that I could find at least.)

The ES documentation says:

the maximum size of the bulk thread pool is 1 +  number-of-available-processors (which is 
auto-detected and can be overridden.)

However, the docs say that overriding the processors setting is

> "an expert-level use-case and there’s a lot more involved than just
>   setting the processors setting as there are other considerations like
>   changing the number of garbage collector threads, pinning processes to
>   cores, etc."

I am hoping there is a nice guide or tutorial that will walk me through all the nuances and gotchas of
changing the  setting for 'processors'.  I did some searching but nothing jumped out for me.

thanks in advance !

NOTE: Elasticsearch developers are currently providing me with a lot of helpful advice, although I have not yet figured out how to address the original question. You can view the details here:
    https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-bump-elasticsearch-processors-setting-in-order-to-increase-thread-pool-bulk-size/98781/2